# Add class to second instance of text

Tags: jquery

Let's say my section contains the pages "Red", "Green" and "Blue". Each page has the title in a H1 tag as well as a shared #sidebar navigation showing all three links. How can I get jQuery to detect the text entered in the H1, find the same text in #sidebar, and add a class to the #sidebar link if a match is found?

HTML:

```
<h1>Red</h1>
<div id="sidebar">
  <a href="#">Red</a><br>
  <a href="#">Green</a><br>
  <a href="#">Blue</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar { float: right; }
.current-section { background: red; }
```

Sorry - I'm a jQuery beginner at best. Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BxCgT/

Comment: If you add some HTML it would make life a lot easier !

Comment: some code/markup would be nice

Comment: Create a [jsFiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net/) and show the link in your question.

Comment: First, which language you code into? Second, upload some code part.

Comment: My apologies - fiddle added to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work ...

```
// get title text
var title = $('h1').text();
// loop anchors in #sidebar
$('#sidebar a').each(function() {
   // if anchor text matches title
   if($(this).text() == title) {
     // add a class
     $(this).addClass(<yourclass>);
   }
});
```

Relevant docs -> [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

I've made an assumption your code looks something like this :

```
<h1>Red</h1>
<div id="sidebar">
   <a href="red.html">Red</a><br>
   <a href="green.html">Green</a><br>
   <a href="blue.html">Blue</a>
</div>
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/LUmNE/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. I added a Fiddle to my question, trying to figure out why yours works and mine doesn't! Thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: @Chris - Yours didnt work because you had selected mootools in jsfiddle, not jquery!

Comment: @Chris try that -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/BxCgT/1/ <- with Jamiec's suggestion

Comment: Hahahaha, d'oh... well spotted! I assumed jQuery would be selected by default - I will bear this in mind from now on :)

Comment: I'd suggest using filter() for such a use-case